# Dar height e overflow-y numa div

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Estou a tentar dar `height` e `overflow-y` numa `div` para limitar o tamanho da `div` e adicionar uma scroll.

Algo como isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para tal estou a carregar uma lista de dados vindos da BD (estou a trabalhar em ASP MVC) na div, e adiciono a `height` e o `overflow-y` na mesma:

```
<div id="divListaEstabs" style="height: 60%; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectall">Seleccionar todos
        <br />
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.estabelecimentos)
        {
            <input type="checkbox" value="@item.IdFilial" name="filialCopia"/>@item.Nome<br />
        }
</div>
```

**Problema?**

É adicionada a scroll na div, mas a mesma não fica limitada na altura, aumentando o tamanho da página (como mostra a imagem):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu tens a altura(height) em %. Experimenta em px:

```
<div id="divListaEstabs" style="height: 60px; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectall">Seleccionar todos
        <br />
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.estabelecimentos)
        {
            <input type="checkbox" value="@item.IdFilial" name="filialCopia"/>@item.Nome<br />
        }
</div>
```

Comment: Era mesmo esse o erro :)

Answer (score 1):

Tente mudar, de heigth para max-heigth, assim vc terá mais flexibilidade e responsividade no modal:

```
<div id="divListaEstabs" style="max-height: 10em; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectall">Seleccionar todos
    <br />
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.estabelecimentos)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" value="@item.IdFilial" name="filialCopia"/>@item.Nome<br />
    }
</div>
```

Comment: eu experimentei isso. O erro estava mesmo onde o pc_oc disse: ao usar % para definir a `height` deixar de dar, tem de ser com `px`

Comment: Eu usaria outra unidade então como `em`, para manter a responsividade da tela.

Comment: Exacto, assim também dá